# Redirect old ASPX URL with commas to new PHP URL

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've searched around quite a bit for this, but haven't come across my exact issue.

I recently rebuilt an old `.aspx` site into WordPress, changing essentially every URL on the site. I have all the redirects in place, except there are a few URL's with commas in them that I can't seem to get to redirect.

The URLs with the commas display an Apache "Forbidden" page.

For example, I have the URL: `/resourceslearn/tools/checklists,-tips,-tools/whitepapers.aspx` that I need redirected to `/whitepapers/`

I'm not very good with regular expressions, let alone htaccess rules, so please forgive me if what I have tried is completely wrong.

I've tried the following rules:

`Redirect 301 /resourceslearn/tools/checklists(.+)-tips(.+)-tools/whitepapers.aspx$ /whitepapers/`

`Redirect 301 /resourceslearn/tools/checklists([^/]+)-tips([^/]+)-tools/whitepapers.aspx$ /whitepapers/`

`Redirect 301 /resourceslearn/tools/checklists,-tips([^/]+)-tools/whitepapers.aspx$ /whitepapers/`

`Redirect 301 /resourceslearn/tools/checklists([^,/]+)-tips([^,/]+)-tools/whitepapers.aspx$ /whitepapers/`

Can anyone give me some assistance on how I can detect the comma in the URL and redirect it to the proper page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use Regex in Redirect , try `RedirectMatch` instead

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/resourceslearn/tools/checklists(.+)-tips(.+)-tools/whitepapers.aspx$ /whitepapers/
```

Reference :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Unfortunately it still returns the Forbidden error page.

Comment: I tried an incognito browser so cache shouldn't be an issue. I'm using the WP Super Cache plugin, would that cache the htaccess file?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in htaccess?

Comment: Ah, I did! I had a security redirect in place that blocked commas. Thank you for your help. The `RedirectMatch` worked.

Answer (score 0):

[`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) doesn't use regular expressions, just a URL-path. This means, you can take the path literally

```
Redirect /resourceslearn/tools/checklists,-tips,-tools/whitepapers.aspx /whitepapers/
```

When it works as it should, you may replace the status code with `301`. Never test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: I have tested this redirect on my system and it works properly, so there must be some other rules or redirects in your htaccess.